# UITableView disappears after appearing from background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to create a music application with a "now playing" bar at the top of it.
I'm using standard storyboarding for the ui (UITabbarController->UINavigationController->UITableviewcontroller)

When someone taps a track in the tableview list a small programmaticcaly created uiview scrolls down under the navigation bar and the tableview moves down.

All this is working great.

However, when the application is send to the background by tapping the home button and reopened again the tableview disappears in an instant. This only happens when tapping the homebutton locking the iPhone and unlocking causes no problems.

This is the code where i animate the UIView in

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
frame.origin.y += 60;
frame.size.height -= 60;

if(!nowPlayingPopDown){
    //setup nowplaying view
    nowPlayingPopDown = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -60, 320, 60)];
    CGRect nowPlayingPopDownAnimatedLocation = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60);

    nowPlayingPopDown.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.view.superview addSubview:nowPlayingPopDown];

    //setup waveform background
    nowPlayingPopDownWaveformBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 0, 60)];
    nowPlayingPopDownWaveformBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [nowPlayingPopDown addSubview:nowPlayingPopDownWaveformBackground];

    //setup waveform imageview
    nowPlayingPopDownWaveform = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 260, 60)];
    [nowPlayingPopDown addSubview:nowPlayingPopDownWaveform];

    //animate nowplaying bar in
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
    nowPlayingPopDown.frame = nowPlayingPopDownAnimatedLocation;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: I'd throw an NSLog in at the top to check the tableView.frame I'm sure its nil when coming back from the background.

Comment: I've just checked it, the frame still has the right property's after returning from the background.

Comment: I have fixed it by creating the tableview programatically in a uiviewcontroller.

Comment: Did you find solution for this ?